# Ограничение ввода EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Всем добрый день! Необходимо чтобы пользователь мог ввести значение в EditText используя цифровую клавиатуру, исключая ввести просто 0, но при этом мог ввести десятичную дробь, например 0,5.

```
 q_input.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcherZero(q_input));
}

//Создаем класс TextWatcher на проверку равенства введенного значения нулю:
public static class TextWatcherZero implements TextWatcher {
    public EditText editText;

    //Конструктор принимающий конкретный EditText
    public TextWatcherZero(EditText et) {
        super();
        editText = et;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        //TODO
        try {
            if (editText.getText().toString().equals("0")) {
                //Всплывающая подсказка при неверном вводе исходных данных
                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                        .make(this.editText, "Данный параметр не может быть равен нулю", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                snackbar.show();
                editText.setText("");
                editText.setFocusable(true);
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Разметка

```
        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/q_input"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="л/с"
        android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textColorHint="#A5A0A0"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
    />
```

Comment: Так не получится - на голый ноль придётся проверять при попытке использовать значение, вы же не можете предугадать будет ли юзер вводить что-то ещё. Соответственно в `TextWatcher` удалять его нельзя - можно только сигнализировать о некорректном значении.

Comment: Как вы представляете ввод 0.5 без ввода 0? Вам нужно проверять при выходе на 0, или аналогично

Comment: Пример: Юзер вводит 0 и переходит к следующему EditText, тогда хотелось бы ткнуть его и сказать ай-яй-яй нехорошо так. Понял, спасибо

Comment: Повесьте на EditText слушатель фокуса - если фокус потерян проверяйте ввод и делайте что надо.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!